# inserting to database with foregn keys

Tags: php, mysql

Iam having a problem with inserting data to my database,

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`forum-design`.`topics`, CONSTRAINT `topics_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`cat_id`))

Comment: what do u actually want?

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key relationships involve a parent table that holds the central data values, and a child table with identical values pointing back to its parent. The FOREIGN KEY clause is specified in the child table.

It will reject any INSERT or UPDATE operation that attempts to create a foreign key value in a child table if there is no a matching candidate key value in the parent table.

I think your problem is :

1) You have a primary key on category_id - and your insert statements do not have value for category_id

2) You have a self referencing foreign key in the form of referrer_id referring to category_id. When you are inserting a record with referrer_id which is not null.

For better understanding follow [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your parent table "categories" doesn't have category id that you try to reference in your child table "forum-design".

Make sure that parent table has the record which you need to reference in a child table.

For example :
Table categories have two records as following.

```
cat_id | cat_name
-----------------
1      | catName1
2      | catName2
```

and while inserting data or updating data of "forum-design" table if you write a value that is not present in categories.cat_id it causes an error that you are facing.

if you look at above table, in this case, use of every other value result in error except 1 and 2.